# Does firebase realtime database for web have offline capability for PWA

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, progressive-web-apps, offline

I have a web project where I use a lot firebase realtime database, now I wanna turn my application into PWA, so I wanna two things

1. When user install an application I wanna cache some part of the database
2. when the user is offline and goes to a page that is trying to download something from the firebase, I want this data to be returned from the cache
3. when the user does some operations, which is usually online, I save the data in the database I wanna firebase save it to "cache" and when the connection appears - save it to database

Looks like firebase for android CAN do this
(ttps://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

But when I read the documentation for the web - I am not sure it is possible
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase realtime DB offers offline capability only for mobile (iOS/Android) development. If you need offline persistence, then you should opt for [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline).

You would receive exactly the features you pointed out in your question. Whenever the user reads some documents, those are cached locally and made available even offline (full CRUD operations available). There is 40MB of cache threshold, after which oldest documents will be removed. You can change this value, increasing or reducing the cache amount.

To enable it:

```
//For mobile development, it is turned on by default
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence() 
  .catch(function(err) {
      if (err.code == 'failed-precondition') {
          // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
          // in one tab at a a time.
          // ...
      } else if (err.code == 'unimplemented') {
          // The current browser does not support all of the
          // features required to enable persistence
          // ...
      }
  });
```

I [wrote an article](https://dev.to/paco_ita/break-the-cache-api-limits-in-our-pwa-oo3) (part of a series about PWAs) where I explain how to use Cloud Firestore offline persistence to overcome CACHE API limits, as it allows to cache only GET Requests.

Comment: `then you should opt for Cloud Firestore.`


The problem here is I already have a lot of code written in the realtime database.

Do you think the best (the simplest) way in my case is rewrite full app to firestore?

Comment: It is a long time since last time I used realtime DB, but for what I can remember the APIs differences are not so big. I do not know how did you designed your solution, but I had also to port a realtime DB solution into a Firestore one and it was not a big work. Therefore I would suggest to pass to Firestore, especially considering the benefits you will receive for offline storage and PWAs. I also used this solution for my projects (as described in my PWA articles).